# gstreamer : audiosink to output stream of integers representing volume levels

Tags: gstreamer

I need a gstreamer audio sink that outputs integers that 
represent volume level of an audio stream. The sampling rate 
need not be the same as the incoming audio stream, it can be much
lower, ex.: one value per second would be sufficient.

Does such a sink exist ?

It seems that this one could be modified to do this :

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-volume.html

But if something already exists I'd prefer to avoid writing one !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there indeed is such an element, it's not a sink though but I don't think you need it to be for that task anyway :)

It is called level (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-level.html), and as you can see there is an "interval" property that you can tweak.

We use this element in our video editor to draw waveforms, here take this simplified script :

```
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GLib

import sys

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

def _messageCb(bus, message):
    if str(type(message.src)) == "<class '__main__.__main__.GstLevel'>":
    s = message.get_structure()
    p = None
    if s:
            p = s.get_value("rms")
        if p:
            st = s.get_value("stream-time")
            print "rms = " + str(p) + "; stream-time = " + str(st)

    if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        mainloop.quit()

    elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        bus.disconnect_by_func(_messageCb)
        mainloop.quit()


if __name__=="__main__":
    global mainloop
    Gst.init([])
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("uridecodebin name=decode uri=" +  sys.argv[1] + " ! audioconvert ! level name=wavelevel interval=10000000 post-messages=true ! fakesink qos=false name=faked")
    faked = pipeline.get_by_name("faked")
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", _messageCb)
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    mainloop.run()
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

May I inquire about your use case ?

Comment: The use case is the same as yours : to draw a waveform, so that is exactly what I need. Thanks !

Comment: Then please come on our IRC (#pitivi on freenode) and discuss with us how to extract our waveform code a little more, it's already quite loosely coupled but it could even be made a library :) We have quite a few features for waveforms, including zoom, scroll etc..